# Enabling Session only for one ASPX page

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

1. I am working on an application that needs to have Session Mode: Off.
2. I need to create a Local Report because some of the clients using the application cannot have access to the reports server.
3. Report Viewer does not work (locally) without enabling Session.

**QUESTION**: Is it possible to enable Session ONLY for the report ASPX page? 
I was thinking there could be a setting in web config.
Maybe something wrapped inside something like this:

```
<location path="reportpage.aspx">
....
</location>
```

**EDIT**:
From your answers it's clear that it cannot be done. Plus I realized I would have problems using session even for one page only. Because the whole project operates under 2 separate IIS Servers dividing the workload and its risky having data in session cause they could easily get lost.

So I guess I'll have to find another way to solve my problem.

For the sake of others who really need to use session on one Page only I will accept the best answer (In my opinion) solving that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that if you turn session mode to off for the application that you can enable it on a single page within that application.  You may be able to put the reports page in another application by itself and enable it that way.

I guess the other way you could do it is to leave session state on for the application, and turn it off using the page directive in every other page:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" 
EnableSessionState="false" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can have session state enabled only for part of your site since it is implemented as module and to my knowledge does not have such granular configuration.